# How to relationalize a JSON to flat structure in AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

Trying to flatten input JSON data having two map/dictionary fields (custom_event1 and custom_event2), which may contain any key-value pair data. In order to create an output table from the data frame, will have to avoid the flattening of custom_events and store it as JSON string in the column.

Following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/) doc, Relationalize.apply is flattening the custom_events map also.

```
Sample JSON:

{
    "id": "sklfsdfskdlfsdfsdfkhsdfssdf",
    "idtype": "cookieId",
    "event": "install",
    "sub_event": null,
    "ip": "XXXXXX",
    "geo": {
        "country": "IN",
        "city": null,
        "region": null
    },
    "carrier": {
        "operator": null,
        "network": null,
        "connection_type": null
    },
    "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "device": {
        "brand": "LYF",
        "model": null,
        "type": null
    },
    "package": {
        "pkgName": "XXXXXXXX",
        "pkgVersion": "1.5.6.3",
        "pkgRating": null,
        "timestamp": "2017-12-14 11:51:27"
    },
    "custom_event1": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    "custom_event2": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

How to store JSON data with a dynamic map field in a Relational storage?

Answer (score 3):

The steps that you would need, assumption that JSON data is in S3

1. Create a Crawler in AWS Glue and let it create a schema in a catalog (database).  Assumption is that you are familiar with AWS Glue a little.
2. Create a Glue job that transforms the JSON into your favorite format (parquet) that uses the transform step to flatten the data using Rationalize class - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/
   and writes to parquet format
3. Create a crawler for the new flatten data and create the table in aws glue
4. Use Athena or AWS Quick sight or your favorite BI tool to query parquet data

Comment: The link has expired @Haroon

Comment: This is the link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/

Comment: What about with nested arrays? People seem to be having success with explode()

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and create a classifier for JSON files following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-json) documentation.

When I executed the crawler, I added the classifier and like as magic all the JSON structure was in a relation model to be stored in a Redshift cluster database.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231